# How to compress a Unix timestamp?

Tags: compression, unix-timestamp

A Unix timestamp expressed in seconds is like the following (rounded up of course)

```
1409134929
```

The issue lies that our system is constrained by memory and we're generating and storing a timestamp every second. They are accessed randomly one by one, so a "whole" compression won't work.

[Smaz](https://github.com/antirez/smaz) won't help as it only compresses short strings, neither **LZMA** is going to cut it.

Is there some special compression algorithm or dictionary technique to achieve this type of compression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a string but a binary value. The POSIX Timestamp (EPOCH) is stored in a 32-bit value (at least on a 32-bit PC).

Storing your timestamp on a string can take 9x8bit=72bits or up to 9x32bits=288bits if a the char type uses a 32-bit memory slot.

Your solution is to get the binary form of your string.

Here what you will get in binary:

[Binary EPOCH](https://web.archive.org/web/20100427005140/http://staticfree.info/software/binaryUnixtime)

If you use the C language, please take a look to the [mktime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/mktime.html) function.

Comment: thanks. didn't think about this method. managed to bring a single timestamp which was 11 bytes long down to 4 bytes!

Comment: or 93.50 % Lossless compression   ----------------- >>>> https://blog.minhazav.dev/compress-sequence-of-unix-timestamps-with-microseconds-accuracy-to-10-bit-accuracy/#source-code

Comment: another example JS    https://medium.com/@polidatacompressor/understanding-datetime-compression-types-6c09daa7d016   BTW. google has patent for timestamp compression !